# what is the difference between accessing an array with a pointer and a non-array variable through a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am attempting to learn C in a little more depth. I have written the code displayed below.

```
#include "includes.h"

int main() {
    char *array[1];
    array[0] = "cloud";
    char *ll[1];
    ll[0] = array[0];
    int n = 20, *pointer; // actual and pointer decaration

    pointer = &n; // assign the memory address of int n to pointer
    printf("the address of the variable in pointer is: %x\n", pointer);
    printf("the value of *pointer is %d\n", *pointer);
    printf("the value of &pointer is %x\n", &n);
    //return 0;

    // to access the value provided by a pointer, you would use *pointer
    // accessing an array directly
    printf("value of array[0] %s\n", array[0]);
    printf("address of &array[0] %x\n", &array[0]);

    // accessing array through the pointer ll
    printf("value of *ll %s\n", *ll);
    printf("address of ll %x\n", ll);
    printf("pointer: %p\n", (void*) pointer); //inclusion from @chux
}
```

The header file "includes.h" contains the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define DEF1 20
#define DEF2 2
```

Here is the program output, as from my Bash Terminal:

```
[carl@sparknohss c]$ ./pointers.bin 
the address of the variable in pointer is: 4a8c27dc
the value of *pointer is: 20
the value of &pointer is: 4a8c27dc
value of array[0]: cloud
address of &array[0]: 4a8c27f0
value of *ll: cloud
address of ll: 4a8c27e0
pointer: 0x7ffc4a8c27dc
[carl@sparknohss c]$
```

I see that there is a difference, at least I think, when accessing a pointer that points to a non-array and when accessing a pointer that points to an array. Is there anyone that can explain this in a little more detail?

Also, what is the difference between `%x` and `%p`, other than the '0x7ffc' prefix provided by `%x`? Are there any good resources that I can delve into for a better explanation?

Comment: Detail: printing a pointer value with specifier `"%x"` is not defined behavior.  Better to use `printf("pointer: %p\n", (void*) pointer);`

Comment: Unclear. What output does your program produce, and what part of that output confuses you?

Comment: I recieve the following output <code>the address of the variable in pointer is: b46e237c
the value of *pointer is 20
the value of &pointer is b46e237c
value of array[0] cloud
address of &array[0] b46e2390
value of *ll cloud
address of ll b46e2380</code> I see that when I declared array as char *array[1] I though I had declared it as a pointer. When I try to access the value of the array[1] like *array[1], i do not get the same output as if I were to do the same with a non-array variable. Sorry, i do not know how to use code blocks in the reply box.

Comment: @Linuxnogui: You should probably edit this into the question itself. Also "cloud address" is not exactly a common term in C.

Comment: @EOF cloud address looks like it is part of the output. It would be a lot more clear if the original question is edited.

Comment: @Linuxnogui what are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: One of your `printf()`s is *severely* misleading: `printf("the value of &pointer is %x\n",&n);` does *not* print the address of `pointer`.

Comment: %x prints an unsigned integer in hex, and %p prints a pointer address. [Here is some more info.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm)

Comment: @Riley `%p` prints the *value* of a pointer, not its address. Which is, not coincidentally, something the OP should probably learn.

Comment: from the output of the non-array pointer, I expected that a similar result would be provided by an array pointer. Unless I am getting confused.

Comment: @EOF Oops, I was typing faster than I was thinking. I meant it prints a pointer address...

Comment: thank you Riley, that helps alot. Are there any other resources that could help me learn about pointers?

Comment: @Linuxnogui That link only really helps with `printf` format specifiers. Pointers are one of the hardest things for most people to learn in C. I would recommend getting a good grasp of the language in general, then get into pointers. As for specifics learning material, I can't think of anything off hand besides taking a class or two. Unfortunately there's really no replacement for hands on experience with an instructor.

Comment: Every address or pointer value must be printed with %p as @chux said.

Comment: @Linuxnogui, can you be more specific about the nature of the difference you're asking about?  How is that reflected in the program output?

Comment: array is declared as a pointer array. When I access it with printf("value of array[0] %s\n", array[0]), I get 'value of array[0]: cloud'. Why does printf("value of *array[0]: %s",*array[0]) result in a 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'. But when I access pointer with printf("the value of *pointer is %d\n", *pointer), I get the value of *pointer is: 20.

Comment: @Linuxnogui: because `*array[0]` is a single `char`, not a pointer (it's equivalent to writing `array[0][0]`).  `%s` expects its corresponding argument to have type `char *` and to point to the first character in a string.  `*array[0]` is just the character `c` - it's not a  valid pointer value, hence the segfault.

Comment: thank you, that explains it a bit better.

Comment: Please clarify, by editing the question, exactly what difference you are referring to with the comment "I see that there is a difference". Say specifically how the output differs from what you expected.

Answer (score 2):

> I see that there is a difference, at least I think, when accessing a pointer that points to a non-array and when accessing a pointer that points to an array. Is there anyone that can explain this in a little more detail?

There are some differences when dealing with arrays and pointer objects.

Setting aside your code for a second, assume you have the declaration

```
int arr[10];
```

This creates an array `arr` large enough to hold 10 integers; it's laid out in memory like so:

```
     +---+ 
arr: |   | arr[0]
     +---+
     |   | arr[1]
     +---+
      ...
     +---+
     |   | arr[9]
     +---+
```

One thing becomes obvious here - the address of the first element of the array (`&arr[0]`) is going to be the same as the address of the whole array object (`&arr`).  The expressions `&arr[0]` and `&arr` will have the same *value*, but their *types* will be different - the type of `&arr[0]` will be "pointer to `int`" (`int *`), while the type of `&arr` will be "pointer to *10-element array of* `int`" (`int (*)[10]`).

Now here's where a wrinkle comes in - except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

This means that the *expression* `arr` *also* evaluates to the address of the first element of the array, just like `&arr[0]` and `&arr`; it "decays" from type "10-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`" (same type as `&arr[0]`).

This is *definitely* different from how regular pointer variables behave.  Given

```
int *ptr;
```

the expression `ptr` does *not* give you the same value as `&ptr` - it gives you the value of whatever is stored in `ptr`.

Going back to your code for a second, in the line

```
array[0] = "cloud";
```

the *string literal* `"cloud"` is itself an array expression - it has type "6-element array of `char`" (counting the 0 terminator).  Since it is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, nor is it being used to initialize another array in a declaration, the expression is converted from type "array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first character in the string.  Since you declared `array` as an array of `char *`, this works; the type of `array[0]` is `char *`.

So, why do array expressions "decay" to pointer expressions?

The array indexing operation `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)` - given an address value, offset `i` elements (**not bytes**) from that address and dereference the result.  This is a holdover from the B programming language from which C was derived, and which used pointers internally when setting up array objects.  C got rid of the internal pointers, but kept the subscript semantics.  So, for `a[i]` to work in C, `a` first has to be converted to a pointer value.  Note that this means you can use the `[]` operator on pointer types - `pointer[0]` and `*pointer` will give you the same result (the value of the thing `pointer` is pointing to).

So, if you print out the following expressions:

```
printf( "&array[0] = %p\n", (void *) &array[0] );
printf( "array     = %p\n", (void *) array );
printf( "&array    = %p\n", (void *) &array );
```

you should see the same value for all three - the address of the first element of `array`.  If you print out the expression

```
printf( "array[0]  = %p\n", (void *) array[0] );
```

you should see the address of the first character of the `"cloud"` string literal.

If you print the expression

```
printf( "array     = %s\n", array );
```

you should see the string `cloud`.  Remember that the `%s` conversion specifier expects its corresponding argument to be a pointer to `char`, and it will print the sequence of characters starting at that address until it sees the 0 terminator.

If you print the expression

```
printf( "*array[0] = %c\n", *array[0] );
```

you will see the character `c` - the first letter in the `"cloud"` string.  Note that `*array[0]` is the same as `array[0][0]`.  To print `l`, you'd write

```
printf( "array[0][1] = %c\n", array[0][1] );
```

If you print the expressions

```
printf( "pointer  = %p\n", (void *) pointer );
printf( "&pointer = %p\n", (void *) &pointer );
```

you should *definitely* see different values since `pointer` is not an array object.

> Also, what is the difference between %x and %p

`%x` expects its corresponding argument to have type `unsigned int`, and formats the output in hexadecimal.

`%p` expects its corresponding argument to have type `void *`, and formats the output in an implementation-defined manner (often hex, but it doesn't have to be).

You do *not* want to use `%x` (or anything other than `%p`) to print out pointer values.  For one thing, a pointer value may be wider than an `unsigned int` (that's true on my system), so the output will likely be garbled.

Comment: "the address of the first element of the array is going to be the same as the address of the whole array object" needs further qualification. They might have different value representations, and attempting to compare the two is a constraint violation. So I think it does not make sense to talk about them having the "same value". The guarantee you do have is that casting both to the same type will produce identical values.